# Simple time counter in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I'm starting to learn React and I want to create a component that compares the current time to starting time and update the view.

Here's how I make it:

```
import React from 'react';

const Timer = ({ callQueuedTime }) => (

    setInterval(function () { 
        console.log("test"); 
        return <p>{new Date().getTime() - new Date(callQueuedTime).getTime()}</p> 
    }, 1000)
)

export default Timer;
```

In devTools, the `console.log` is refreshing every 1 sec but not the HTML. Also, I'm always getting the same value, which is not the value of `new Date().getTime() - new Date(callQueuedTime).getTime()`

For information `callQueuedTime= 2020-04-23T22:02:07.382Z`

**UPDATE**

I have updated my component code:

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context)
        this.state = {
            timer: 0,
        }

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props)
        setInterval(function () {
            const time = new Date().getTime() - new Date(this.props.callQueuedTime).getTime()
            this.setState({ time });
        }, 1000)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <p>{this.state.timer}</p>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, after the first second, I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'callQueuedTime' of undefined

Comment: Make `state` and update State every one Second by using `useEffect` hook is simplest way

Comment: Returning a value from the setInterval callback is pointless—update the state and display it instead.

Comment: Please read up on component life cycle. You need to re-render the page for it to display the changed value. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

In any case, I would not try to return that <p> element every second, I would store that date variable separately (in the state - and use a function with setinterval inside to update the state every second), then display that variable in the render/return function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely do this with a functional component.

As noted, you can't return JSX from a setInterval call. setInterval returns an id to use to clear.

The way I go about this is to keep the time as state, and then update that time every second in an effect.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Timer = ({ callQueuedTime }) => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(() => new Date().getTime());
  useEffect(() => {
    const queuedTime = new Date(callQueuedTime).getTime();
    const intervalId = setInterval(function () {
      setTime(new Date().getTime() - queuedTime);
    }, 1000);
    return ()=>{
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, [callQueuedTime]);
  return <p>{time}</p>;
};

export default Timer;
```

The function being returned in the `useEffect` is the cleanup function. It is called before the useEffect runs the next time and before the component unmounts.
For further reading:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup

https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Here's the working code as a class component:

The issue you were running into was that you were using a function in the setInterval rather than an arrow function, so you were losing access to your component's `this`. The other issue you would run into is that you weren't cleaning up your interval on unmount.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class TimerComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { time: 0 };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            const time =
        new Date().getTime() - new Date(this.props.callQueuedTime).getTime();
      this.setState({ time });
    }, 1000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }
  render() {
    return <p>{this.state.time}</p>;
  }
}
```

Here's a stackblitz showcasing both options:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-w2gqa6?file=Timer.jsx

Comment: Thanks , that's working. Can you add an example using Class component by correcting my update, so that I can see the difference between the components types ?

Comment: Okay, I added the class based component as requested. I also changed the functional component so you can more directly compare the two.

Comment: What does the return of the useEffect ?

Comment: I added some explanations and links for further reading. I highly recommend the overreacted blog as it gives a great explanation for useEffect as a whole and some of the design decisions that went into it.